# classes and inheritance in python3

Tags: python-3.5

```
class Myclass(list):

    def remove_max(self):
        self.remove(max(self))

l = [1,2,3]

object = Myclass(l)

object.remove_max()

print(object)
```

in Myclass which inherits from class list why does the Myclass(l) assign the object a value [1,2,3]?
And even if we gave it a string say 'abc' instead of list l as an input why is the value of object set as the list ['a'. 'b']?

Comment: Could you please clarify the code and the question? I would guess the last four lines are not supposed to have indentation?
And what do you mean with "assign"? `object = Myclass(l)` assigns `[1,2,3]` as the [list constructor](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#list) would. The next line removes the element `3`.

Comment: yeah im sorry for the incorrect indentation.i have edited the code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you do not define an `__init__` method, the parameter given at construction time is given to the immediate parent, here `list`. And when you build a list from an iterable, you get the list composed from the different items. So:

- if `l` is a list `list(l)` is a copy of the initial list
- if `s` is a string (which is an iterable of characters), `list(s)` is the list composed with the characters from `s`